How can I automatically save WooCommerce API key details as user meta when an API key is created?
Whenever I create an API key on this WooCommerce page: /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=advanced&section=keys
I want to automatically save the API key details (such as Consumer Key and Secret) as meta fields in the user's account associated with that API key.
add_action('woocommerce_api_key_save', 'save_api_key_to_user_meta', 10, 1);

function save_api_key_to_user_meta($key_id) {
    // Retrieve the API key details using the key ID
    $key = WC()->api->get_key($key_id);

    if ($key && !is_wp_error($key)) {
        // Get the user ID associated with the API key
        $user_id = $key->user_id;

        // Save the API key details as user meta, hashing the consumer_secret
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'woocommerce_api_key_id', $key_id);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'woocommerce_api_consumer_key', $key->consumer_key);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'woocommerce_api_consumer_secret_hash', wp_hash_password($key->consumer_secret));
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'woocommerce_api_key_permissions', $key->permissions);
    }
}

The code doesn't seem to work as there is nothing related in the wp_usermeta database table…

it didn't work . i checked the user database. nothing there @LoicTheAztec

You should try to enable WP Debug as explained in HERE… Once done, try to add in your function the following code line, just before the IF statement: error_log( print_r($key, true)); to check what do you get from $key variable and if there is an available user ID…

After searching a bit, note that there is no woocommerce_api_key_save hook and no  get_key() available method for that in WooCommerce. Apparently, each generated API key is saved via Admin Ajax, so for example, the composite action hook woocommerce_update_options_advanced_keys get never triggered. Sorry, I have no clue yet.
